# webpack2 and webpack dev server - run a shell command everytime a file is changed

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an application built using webpack and webpack-dev-server.
webpack-dev-server is being called using node api.
e.g. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/examples/node-api-simple/server.js

Everytime a file is changed and a new build happens i'd like to execute a shell command. Where could i configure webpack or webpack-dev-server to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the webpack shell plugin?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin

Comment: i did not. I will take a look. Thanks!